# VSCommands Solution Badges parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

does anyone know what are the various parameters for VSCommands's Solution Badges feature? On the official site http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionBadges they tell you everything BUT the most important thing and that is the list of available parameters (ie. {solutionFileName}, {sln:activeConfig}, {branchDirectoryName} and so on). Can't seem to be able to google them either. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that pretty much all available parameters are already displayed with the default configuration (had to decompile and deobfuscate the extension to find out this information). What I was after was full solution path in the window's title bar. I solved the problem with this handy extension 
[Visual Studio Window Title Changer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239/).